# Cell color based on colour value in another cell

Tags: excel

I'd ideally like to do this without VBA but if that's the only option that makes sense I guess I'll go with that :)

I have a set of cells that require formatting and then another set of cells that define my style, ie background color, font color. Is it possible to have Excel set the background color or a cell font based on instructions in a cell.  If I can get even just the background color that would be great.

```
Cell
1
2
3
```

Instructions

```
 Background Color  FFFFF
 Font Color        FFFFF
```

FYI I'm using Excel 2010 on Windows 7.  Some background : I have tables that are styled so headers and certain rows take specific colours but for the next report iteration I'd like different colours assigned but want to automate that formatting.

Comment: If there is some sort of relationship between the color and value, you could use conditional formatting. Is this a possibility?

Comment: No relationship. Have tables that are styled so headers and certain rows take specific colours but for the next report iteration I'd like different colours assigned but want to automate that formatting.

Comment: I'd rather not use VBA if there's an alternative using formulas or GUI interface.

Comment: Can you expand on what a XLM solution might entail? Thanks!

Comment: From the link, "Not recommended because of reliance on the XLM (not XML) Macro function GET.CELL. This from a technology introduced 30 years ago that was effectively superseded eight years later. With almost all its elements now defunct, the few that remain can be expected to have a low life expectancy. Microsoft encourages migration to VBA."  Why don't you want VBA? It might be preferred over this old method.  VBA can do this, no problemo.

Comment: There are 60+ tables with formatting, but really only 4 to 6 colours, so writing the VBA code will take a while. Next year I have to go change all 4 to 6 colours across all the tables. But the tables aren't structured well enough to use a custom table style or conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Id suggest trying to use Conditional Formatting tools. They are pretty flexible